# Cross-referencing items in two-level enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

In LaTeX I have an enumerate environment embedded inside another enumerate environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item now we have another list\label{lab1}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item item one of second list
\item item two of second list\label{lab2}
\end{enumerate}
\item or another case
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I want to refer to part (i)(b), and have tried using `\eqref{lab1}\eqref{lab2}`. This produces the result (i)(ib). What is the correct way to obtain (i)(b)?

**Note:** This question has been migrated here from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the package `enumitem` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item now we have another list\label{lab1}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),ref=\theenumi(\alph*)]
  \item item one of second list
  \item item two of second list\label{lab2}
  \end{enumerate}
\item or another case
\end{enumerate}

References: \ref{lab1} \ref{lab2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No need in this case for `ref=(\roman*)`. Also `ref=\theenumi(\alph*)` produces what the OP wanted to avoid...

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, I know. I'll remove it.

Comment: **N.B.** this only works if you explicitly define the type of enumerated sublist. I lost a ton of time trying to make this work because the default sublist was alphabetical, which is what I wanted, but apparently failure to include `[label=(\alph*)]` when defining the sublist will still lead to the original problem, even though it has no visible effect on the appearance of the sublist.

Answer (score 8):

The `enumerate` package doesn't really give you a handle on the reference form. You could use `enumitem` package instead, but here I'd simply do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\theenumi{(\roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi}

\renewcommand\theenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii}



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item now we have another list\label{lab1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item one of second list
\item item two of second list\label{lab2}
\end{enumerate}
\item or another case
\end{enumerate}


xxx\ref{lab1}xxxxxx\ref{lab2}xxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Too bad the author of `enumerate` didn't think to this.

Comment: @egreg, actually he did but couldn't think of a way of specifying the formatting in the minimalist enumerate interface.